# Dynamic UserForm Name in a Class Module

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code in a Class Module

```
Public WithEvents chk As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub chk_Click()
    Dim c As Object, sName As String

    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
         If c.Type = 3 Then
             If IsLoaded(c.Name) Then
                If chk = True Then
                    UserForm1.lblCount.Caption = CInt(UserForm1.lblCount.Caption) + 1
                Else
                    UserForm1.lblCount.Caption = CInt(UserForm1.lblCount.Caption) - 1
                End If
            End If
         End If
    Next

End Sub

Function IsLoaded(formName As String) As Boolean
    Dim frm As Object

    For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
        If frm.Name = formName Then
            IsLoaded = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next frm
    IsLoaded = False

End Function
```

This works fine when UserForm 1 is loaded. However, UserForm1 gets created at runtime by code in a standard module and the created Userform could be named UserForm2 or UserForm3 or UserForm4 etc.

c.Name returns the correct userform name, I am struggling to get "UserForm1" replaced with "c.Name"

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use the actual instance of the Userform not it's code name.  Read: [Rubberduck VBA: UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)

Comment: Thanks, TinMan, I will read that article